# Unable to extract og tags from webpage?

Tags: php, facebook-opengraph

Here is the code that I am using at this point

```
$file = array_rand($files);
$filename = "http://example.com/".$files[$file];
echo $filename;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$c = file_get_contents($filename);
$d = new DomDocument();
$d->loadHTML($c);
$xp = new domxpath($d);
foreach ($xp->query("//meta[@name='og:title']") as $el) {
echo $el->getAttribute("content");
}
foreach ($xp->query("//meta[@name='og:image']") as $el) {
echo $el->getAttribute("content");
}
```

$filename has correct value of URL but it does not echo the content of og:image and og:title?

**EDIT**

This is the typical organization of my webpages

```
<?php require_once("headertop.php")?>
<meta property="og:image" content="url" />
<meta property="og:title" content="content here." />
<meta property="og:description" content="description here." />
<title>Page title</title>
<?php require_once("headerbottom.php")?>
```

**EDIT 2**

```
From one answer I understood this. I have to use

$rootNamespace = $d->lookupNamespaceUri($d->namespaceURI);
$xpath->registerNamespace('og', $rootNamespace);
```

and then use

```
<meta property="og:image" content="url" />
```

Am I right?

Comment: It might be useful to see the content of an input file.

Answer (score 0):

'og' is a *namespace*, and so it's not going to get pulled in that fashion. You'll need to define that namespace for your DOMXPath object:

http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registernamespace.php

Edit: Here is an example I threw together using VICE's homepage. I pulled the Facebook OpenGraph XML namespace from their Developers site.

```
<?php                                                                              
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
$html = file_get_contents("http://www.vice.com/");
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);
$xp->registerNamespace('og', 'http://ogp.me/ns#');
print_r($xp->query("//meta[@name='og:title']")->item(0)->getAttribute('content'));
```

Comment: I am editing my question again, please take a look and tell me if  I am doing it right.

Comment: You did not paste the definition for `og` in your example page. It's got to be in there somewhere... in `headertop.php` perhaps?

Comment: Hey Todd, i edited the question to include the code that I think I need to add am I correct?

Comment: If `$d->namespaceURI` is the URI specific to the `og` prefix, then yes, that code should work. I'll try to slap together an abstract demo to test it out.

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine:

```
<?php
$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHTML(file_get_contents('http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/'));

foreach($html->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $meta) {
    if(strpos($meta->getAttribute('property'), 'og') !==false) {
        echo $meta->getAttribute('content') . '<br/>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: It did not give any output

Comment: Well it certainly does for me.